# Xcode requires to put _ before return value name in completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, completionhandler

I have a completion handler function with a string in return value.

```
func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {}
```

However, Xcode requires me to put _ before my return value name so I have to put _ before result

```
func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (_ result: String) -> Void) {}
```

and because of that, when I call my function, my return value doesn't have name but instead it shows this

```
hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (String) -> Void)
```

Is there a way that instead of showing

```
completion: (String) -> Void)
```

I want it to show

```
completion: result -> Void)
```

so that I know exactly what return value means instead of the completion type. Thanks!

Comment: This Swift feature has been discussed before in some post, remember it start from Swift 3.2, I find it really bad also, but there's no way to show param names for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some version of Swift, closure types can't have parameter names. However, there is a workaround:

```
typealias Result = String
```

And now you can use `Result` as the closure type:

```
func f(completion: (Result) -> Void) { ... }
```

Many methods in `Foundation` also does this. For example `TimeInterval` is just an alias for `Double`, but naming it `TimeInterval` makes the purpose clearer.

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of this, unless the context makes the data type absolutely clear.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but  the return value also includes view Controller name where I declare typealias. Do you have that issue as well? I look like this "ViewControllerName.Result"

Comment: You need to declare the typealias in the global scope, not inside any VC. @KevinVuD

Comment: Yeah. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add labels for closure definition. Just define it like this.

```
func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {}
```

When this function called, you should define the label.

```
hardProcessingWithString(input: "") { (result) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design (though, to be sure, not everyone likes it). See

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2894

As Jordan Rose explains:

> This is correct behavior. The argument labels are considered part of a function's name, not its type. A function value / closure has only a base name and no argument labels, so they cannot be specified.